# How can I make Python's coverage tool fail if any unit tests fail?

Tags: python, unit-testing, coverage.py

I want to use a shell script to make sure that my unit tests pass **and** that my code has sufficient test coverage.  I only want to run my test code **once**.

I was hoping that I could run my tests via the [coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/) tool and that from that single run:

1. If one or more tests failed, the 'coverage run' command would fail, which would communicate to my shell script that something went wrong.
2. Or if the coverage was insufficient, the 'coverage run' command would fail (using --fail-under).

How would you do that without redirecting command output and searching for key words (e.g. fail)?

Comment: Are you using [pytest-cov](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cov)?  I am not at work right now to look at the setup I am using, by I think what you are asking is the default for pytest-cov.

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't just work as it is? How are you running your tests?

Comment: You have it in reverse: it's apparently impossible _not_ to fail.  I have tried to get `coverage` to run even with some failing testcases and it can't be done afaik. Even have an SOF on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941872/how-to-run-code-coverage-to-completion-with-the-report-even-if-pytest-is-failing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`coverage run` will exit with the exit status of the program you are running. If you run your test runner that way, then the exit status should be passed through transparently.