# Python's multi coverage fail if unit tests fail

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have .sh with many coverage commands

```
coverage run --source=source1 -m unittest  discover -t .  source1 -v
coverage run --source=source2 -m unittest  discover -t .  source2 -v
```

I expect if a unittest failed, the coverage run would fail, and then the complete sh command would fail, but it is not the case.

What is the correct way to make it fail?

Comment: Per e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52107910/3001761 I'd expect `coverage run` *would* pass through the exit code from the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Coverage.py will exit with the same status code as your program run without coverage.  Is there some other detail you are leaving out?  Can you give us a complete runnable example to see what you are seeing?