# How to run code coverage to completion with the report even if pytest is failing?

Tags: python, coverage.py

We have some test cases that are known to fail: those are in our backlog to complete. The tests that fail are not consistent.

I have a separate branch that cleans this all up: but we need the coverage done before that other PR can be merged due to its complexity. We have maybe a hundred test `skip`'s already.

I was unable to find command line option for `coverage` to do this.

What has been tried:

`python -m` . This runs the tests but does not generate coverage info.

Here is the `coverage --help`:

```
$coverage --help
Coverage.py, version 7.2.2 with C extension
Measure, collect, and report on code coverage in Python programs.

usage: coverage <command> [options] [args]

Commands:
    annotate    Annotate source files with execution information.
    combine     Combine a number of data files.
    debug       Display information about the internals of coverage.py
    erase       Erase previously collected coverage data.
    help        Get help on using coverage.py.
    html        Create an HTML report.
    json        Create a JSON report of coverage results.
    lcov        Create an LCOV report of coverage results.
    report      Report coverage stats on modules.
    run         Run a Python program and measure code execution.
    xml         Create an XML report of coverage results.
```

What is the mechanism to force an output?

Comment: Why don't you _skip_ the tests that are failing?

Comment: See https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/skipping.html.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  The tests that fail are not consistent. In a more general sense: I have a  separate branch that cleans this all up: but we need the `coverage` done before that other PR can be merged due to its complexity.  We have maybe a hundred `skip`'s already btw.

Comment: The comments to `skip` do not take into account that we already have a large number of `skip`s but do not want to pollute the codebase in this branch with more when the testing is already fixe in another branch that can not presently be merged. This is a large enterprise codebase in production so integrating large PR's can extend to weeks.

Comment: However you do it is probably going to be opinion based. You can wrap the failing asserts with an environment variable guard so it runs the test, but just doesn't check that assertion. You can assert(PROFILE or condition). You can comment them out.

Comment: @KennyOstrom This question is about how to run coverage _irregardless_ of python test failures.  Again - we have a separate branch to fix the test failures (dozens of failures out of the 800+ total testcases). _No source code changes are going to be made to  *skip* or *swallow* errors_ .  

Maybe the answer is "it can't be done".  It's *not*  "skip tests"

Comment: I was saying how you can change the code without changing the code. But with no changes at all? You'd have to patch the asserts themselves (but that would happen in code so technically still a change -- you can't even import?)

Comment: @KennyOstrom  Correct: no _codebase_ changes. Changes _only_ in the invocation of _coverage_

Comment: What about auto-generating a copy of the codebase, where you patch the asserts to pass, and profile that?

Comment: If there's no support to force a result from `coverage` then I'll update the `pytest` targets to exclude the failing tests.